# Property displayed as undefined in React Component - Retrieve props.match and additional property in component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an index.js from which i am calling a Component like this

```
const prop1 = 'test'
ReactDOM.render(

<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/pathname/:param1/:param2" component={MyComponent} prop1={prop1}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But in MyComponent.js, `this.props.prop1` is displayed as undefined. Any idea why ?
I need to able to get this.props.match.params and prop1

Comment: `Route` only passes the route props, `history`, `match` and `location`, to the components it mounts.

Answer (score 1):

**@jonrsharpe** 's comment is very important:

> Route only passes the route props, history, match and location, to the
>   components it mounts.

So, if you want to pass props to your component in the Route, it should be like this:

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/pathname" render={() => (<MyComponent prop1={prop1}/>)} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: issue with this approach is, props, history, match and location, are not passed to the component , only prop1  is passed.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to pass a prop to a component being rendered by React Router, instead of using Routes component prop, use its render prop passing it an inline function then pass along the arguments to the element you’re creating.

```
<Route
  path='/pathname'
  render={(prop1) => <MyComponent props={prop1} />}
/>
```

please try this, should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const prop1 = 'test'
ReactDOM.render(

<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/pathname/" component={() => <MyComponent prop1={prop1}>} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: The issue here is, i am getting prop1, but not getting props.match (because i have path parameters and i need to get those in the Mycomponent).

Answer (score 0):

This will pass match, location, history and custom prop to new component.

```
const prop1 = 'test'
ReactDOM.render(

<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/pathname/:param1/:param2" render={(props) => <MyComponent {...props} prop1={prop1} />} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Code Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-3mglu)